# pc to mobile chat using bluetooth?

Tags: java, java-me

i want my program to send and receive text from the pc. there should be a client and server software. The server will be running in PC and the client software will be running in Mobile (Nokia Symbian S60 v5 OS). can any one show me a sample code which does it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire J2ME bluetooth API that has code examples. See [JSR82-Spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr082/index2.html).